# Multiple HTTP Requests in Guards

Tags: angular

I have the following routing config:

```
{
  path: '',
  canActivate: [AppGuard],
  children: [
    {
      path: 'login',
      loadChildren: ...
    }
  ]
}
```

The guard (simplified):

```
canActivate(route, state) {
  return this.profileService.get().pipe(
    map(profile => {
      // I have to implement a not logged user
      if (!profile) {
        // No need to redirect
        if (alreadyOnLoginPage) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return this.router.createUrlTree(['/login']);
        }
      }
      // Some unnecessary logic here (redirection to the profile page)...
    })
  );
}
```

Here we have two scenarios:

- OK (1 request):

  1. Go straight to the `/login`
  2. Profile is fetched
  3. No profile, you **are** on the login page already, so return true.
- Not OK (2 requests):

  1. Go to the `/`
  2. Profile is fetched
  3. No profile, you are **not** on the login page, so redirect to `/login`
  4. Here guard is invoking one more time, so profile is fetched again.
  5. No profile, you **are** on the login page already, so return true.

So, as you can see, two requests were invoked in the second scenario. I tried to multicast the service observable, but still have no success.

What should I do so only one request is invoked?

Comment: You have your guard on `path: ''` so it will activate every time it hits a page. The first time, it will be hit when you go to `/` page and the second time when you go to the `/login` page.

Answer (score 0):

In your  guard have a profile property in class, it will be there because its a injectable and singleton guard troughout app.

Change your guard to :-

```
public profile;

canActivate(route, state) {
  const obs = this.profile ? of(this.profile): this.profileService.get();
  return obs.pipe(
    map(profile => {
      // I have to implement a not logged user
      if (!profile) {
        // No need to redirect
        if (alreadyOnLoginPage) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return this.router.createUrlTree(['/login']);
        }
      }
      // Some unnecessary logic here (redirection to the profile page)...
    })
  );
}
```